# Override method declaration in inherited class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Let's say I have this javascript module that I have imported

```js
class A {
  set (k, v) {
  }
}
```

And I implement my own class based on that module

```js
import A from 'module'

class B extends A {
  set (k, o) {
    super.set(k, o.v)
    // other stuff...
  }
}
```

This code works fine, but I'm porting my part as typescript (I'm new to typescript). 
Luckily, the module I'm importing has it's types definition, something like

```
class A<T> {
  set(k: string, v: T): void;
}
```

And I'm implementing it like this

```
class T2 {
  v: T1;
}

class B extends A<T1> {
  set(k: string, o: T2): void {
    super.set(k, o.v)
  }
}
```

But typescript seems to don't like this. I keep getting this error

```
Type '(k: string, v: T2) => void' is not assignable to type '(k: string, value: T1): void;'
```

Not sure how to *mutate* the arguments of that method. How can I achieve the valid javascript from my snippet in typescript?

Comment: I don’t know if TypeScript has a way to force it to accept that, but you shouldn’t override a method with an incompatible signature anyway, because you already said any `B` was an `A<T1>` and so a function accepting an `A<T1>` should be able to call `.set(k, o)` on that object with an `o` that’s a `T1`, not a `T2`.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is pointing out that `B` is not actually *substitutable* for `A<T1>` because `B#set` is not compatible with `A#set`.  To make `B` substitutable for `A<T1>` you need to allow for someone to call `set` with a `T1`:

```
class B extends A<T1> {
  set(k: string, o: T1 | T2): void {
    if (o instanceof T2) {
      super.set(k, o.v); // Our new overload
    } else {
      super.set(k, o);  // The contract that A<T1> *must* support.
    }
  }
}
```